# Excalibur initdb - Invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x, debian

I'm trying [Excalibur](https://pypi.org/project/excalibur-py/) in `Debian` 9.13. I'm following the documentation and installed `Ghostscript` before. When I run `pip install excalibur-py`, terminal returns me:

```
Successfully installed Click-7.1.2 Flask-1.1.2 PyPDF2-1.26.0 SQLAlchemy-1.3.19 Werkzeug-0.16.1 amqp-2.6.1 billiard-3.6.3.0 camelot-py-0.8.2 celery-4.4.7 chardet-3.0.4 configparser-3.5.3 et-xmlfile-1.0.1 excalibur-py-0.4.3 itsdangerous-1.1.0 jdcal-1.4.1 kombu-4.6.11 openpyxl-2.6.4 pandas-0.25.3 pdfminer.six-20200726 python-dateutil-2.8 .1 sortedcontainers-2.2.2 vine-1.3.0
```

Eveything seems to be ok, but when I run `excalibur initdb`, I have this error :

```
Creating new Excalibur configuration file in: /root/excalibur/excalibur.cfg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/excalibur", line 5, in <module>
    from excalibur.cli import cli
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/excalibur/cli.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .tasks import split, extract
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/excalibur/tasks.py", line 10, in <module>
    import camelot
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/camelot/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .__version__ import __version__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/camelot/__version__.py", line 11
    version_parts.append(f"-{prerelease}")
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Have I missed something ? I don't understand this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem + one more on Win 7 32 bit Python 3.5.

1. So the problem is in "f" in the line version_parts.append(f"-{prerelease}"). I removed all instances where there's an f before strings...e.g.

the above line in code would be
version_parts.append("-{prerelease}")
You will have to modify all files like this.

2. in the file lib\site-packages\camelot\handles.py make the following corrections:
   2.1. func: _save_page: line 109 in my code:
   present: fpath = os.path.join(temp, "page-{page}.pdf")
   correction: fpath = os.path.join(temp, "page-{}.pdf".format(page))
   2.2. func: parse: line 168 in my code:
   present: os.path.join(tempdir, "page-{p}.pdf") for p in self.pages
   correction: os.path.join(tempdir, "page-{}.pdf".format(p)) for p in self.pages

Now the func read_pdf is running fine. I have not used any other utility, so i cannot assure you that the above modifications will not create problems.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I also removed some `f` in `core.py`, `stream.py` and `utils.py` to run `excalibur initdb`. Now I don't have error messages anymore and I can access to  `http://localhost:5000` but processing never stop. I think it's damage the tool because some variables can't be reached. [Formated string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) are avalaible since Python 3.6 and I'm using Python 3.5, that could be the issue.